# Can't access browserAction in Firefox extension browser object

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-action

How to access the `browserAction` on a Firefox extension while using manifest version 3?

From the `background.js` trying to access the browserAction as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction), it shows as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In manifest version 3, Chrome replaced `browserAction` and `pageAction` with a unified [action API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/action). For example, in a Chrome MV3 extension, one would use `chrome.action` instead of `chrome.browserAction`.

Which seems to be mirrored in Mozilla Firefox manifest version 3 adaptation, while still not having the documentation updated.